# MySql Error Code: 1005 Can't create table errno: 150

Tags: mysql, database, syntax

MySql workbench reports that my syntax is error free. I can't figure out what's wrong with my database. Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `login` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `pass` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    `fname` VARCHAR(35),
    `lname` VARCHAR(35),
    `gender` VARCHAR(1),
    `phone` VARCHAR(12),
    `appointments` INT,
    `groups` INT(1) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`groups`) references `groups`(`gnumber`)
);

CREATE TABLE `groups` (
    `gname` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    `gnumber` INT(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `groups`(`gname`, `gnumber`) values ('user', 0);
INSERT INTO `groups`(`gname`, `gnumber`) values ('admin', 1);
INSERT INTO `users`(`login`, `pass`, `groups`) values ('admin', 'secret', 1);
```

Comment: Reverse the order of table creation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error Code `150` means:

> If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed.

To fix this, simply create the `groups` Table before the `users` Table.

**Edit:** You'll also need to make `gnumber` a key in the `groups` table for this to work.

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `gname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `gnumber` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gnumber`)
);
```

I don't know whether you want it to be the primary key, you'll have to play around with the available settings but this works for me locally insofar that I can create the tables and execute the inserts.

Comment: I do so and it will create `groups` fine, but I get the same error when creating `users`.

Comment: @user2973522 you'll need to make `gnumber` a key. I added an example for this in my answer.

Comment: Oddly enough, I was getting this error because I was using `table.column` instead of `table(column)` syntax.